# Why is my equation not true on all elements?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

Consider a finite field $F_{17}$. In this, $\omega = 4$ is the primitive $4$th root of unity.

So there is a subgroup $\Omega = \{1, \omega, \omega^2, \omega^3\}$

Consider a polynomial $f \in F_{17}[x]$

And a 2nd polynomial $t$ built from $f$ as

$t(1) = f(1)$ and $t(\omega^s) = \prod_{i=0}^s f(a)$ for $s = 1, \omega, \omega^2, \omega^3$

i.e.

$t(1) = f(1)$

$t(\omega) = f(1)\cdot f(\omega)$

$t(\omega^2) = f(1)\cdot f(\omega)\cdot f(\omega^2)$

$t(\omega^3) = f(1)\cdot f(\omega)\cdot f(\omega^2) \cdot f(\omega^3)$

Now I consider 2 cases with 2 different $f$ polynomials

**Case 1)** $f = 3x^2 + 4x + 11$

For this, I create $t$ as langrange interpolation of these points.

$points=[(\omega^0,f(\omega^0)),(\omega,f(\omega^0)*f(\omega)),(\omega^2,f(\omega^0)*f(\omega)*f(\omega^2)),(\omega^3,f(\omega^0)* f(\omega)*f(\omega^2)*f(\omega^3))]$

$t = 10x^3 + 3x^2 + 15x + 7$

I can express the $t$ polynomial in terms of $f$ as

$t(\omega \cdot x) = t(x) \cdot f(\omega \cdot x)$

In this case, this equation,

$t(\omega \cdot x) = t(x) \cdot f(\omega \cdot )$

holds for all $x \in \{1, \omega, \omega^2, \omega^3\}$

**Case 2)** $f = 3x^2 + 4x + 7$

Here, I get through lagrange interpolation

$t = 6x^3 + 13x^2 + 11x + 1$

For this pair of $f$ & $t$ however, this equation $t(\omega \cdot x) = t(x) \cdot f(\omega \cdot x )$ doesn't hold for all elements of $\Omega$. It holds for $1, \omega, \omega^2$,

but with $x = \omega^3$

$t(\omega\cdot x) = 14$

while

$f(\omega \cdot x) \cdot t(x) = 11$

I am unable to understand why it's not true in all cases.

Is there a better way to express the relation $t(\omega \cdot x) = t(x) \cdot f(\omega \cdot x )$ so that it holds at all points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you defined $t(1)=f(1)$ the relation
$$t(\omega x)=t(x)f(\omega x)$$
can hold at $x=\omega^3$ only when $t(\omega^4)=t(\omega^3)f(\omega^4)$. Or, when
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(1)=t(1)=t(\omega^4)&=t(\omega\cdot\omega^3)\\
&=t(\omega^3)f(\omega^4)\\
&=f(1)f(\omega)f(\omega^2)f(\omega^3)f(\omega^4).
\end{aligned}
$$
Cancelling the factor $f(1)=f(\omega^4)$ you get the requirement
$$
f(1)f(\omega)f(\omega^2)f(\omega^3)=1\qquad(*)
$$
as a consequence.

Your first choice of $f$ satisfies $(*)$ but the second choice does not.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a better way I can describe the relation between $f$ & $t$ rather than $t(\omega \cdot x) = t(x) \cdot f(\omega \cdot x )$. Something which will be true always

Comment: I don't see anything other than only requiring that equation to hold when $x=1,\omega,\omega^2$, and then including the requirement $t(1)=f(1)$ as the fourth equation. Four interpolation points determine a cubic uniquely already. Because you are looking at the values on the cyclic group of four elements, it looks like that is all. Too late an hour, may be I'm not getting what you want/need here?

Comment: `may be I'm not getting what you want/need here?` - I am trying to create a single  equation for $t$ based on $f$ such that it will hold at all points.